# How pass these new messages to another class

Tags: java, multithreading, design-patterns, concurrency, threadpool

Now basically I have created three classes.

```
public void run() {  
int seqId = 0;  
while(true) {  
    List<KamMessage> list = null;  
    try {  
        list = fullPoll(seqId);  
    } catch (Exception e1) {  
        e1.printStackTrace();  
    }  
    if (!list.isEmpty()) {  
        seqId = list.get(0).getSequence();  
        incomingMessages.addAll(list);  
        System.out.println("waiting 3 seconds");  
        System.out.println("new incoming message");  
    }  
    try {  
        Thread.sleep(3000);  
        System.out.println("new incoming message");  
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {  
        e.printStackTrace();  
    }   
   }  
 }  
 public List<KamMessage> fullPoll(int lastSeq) throws Exception {  
 Statement st = dbConnection.createStatement();  
 ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select * from msg_new_to_bde where ACTION =  804 and SEQ >" +  
 lastSeq + "order by SEQ DESC");        
 List<KamMessage> pojoCol = new ArrayList<KamMessage>();  
  while (rs.next()) {  
    KamMessage filedClass = convertRecordsetToPojo(rs);  
    pojoCol.add(filedClass);  
  }  
for (KamMessage pojoClass : pojoCol) {  
    System.out.print(" " + pojoClass.getSequence());  
    System.out.print(" " + pojoClass.getTableName());  
    System.out.print(" " + pojoClass.getAction());  
    System.out.print(" " + pojoClass.getKeyInfo1());  
    System.out.print(" " + pojoClass.getKeyInfo2());  
    System.out.println(" " + pojoClass.getEntryTime());  
   }             
return pojoCol;  
  }
```

The following are the classes:
  1.Poller- does the Polling and Passes the new data from db to controller

2.Controller- this class has a thread Pool, which simultaneously calls the Poller and has the new data to be requested from processor

3.Processor- this class has to look for new data, process it and return it to controller.

So now my problem is how to implement the third phase...

Here is my controller class:

```
public class RunnableController {  

/** Here This Queue initializes the DB and have the collection of incoming message
 *                    
 */  
  private static Collection<KpiMessage> incomingQueue = new ArrayList<KpiMessage>();  
  private Connection dbConncetion;  
  public ExecutorService threadExecutor;  
  private void initializeDb()  
  {  
    //catching exception must be adapted - generic type Exception prohibited  
    DBhandler conn = new DBhandler();  
    try {  
        dbConncetion = conn.initializeDB();  
    } catch (Exception e) {  
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block  
        e.printStackTrace();  
     }  
  }  


private void initialiseThreads()  
{         
    try {  

        threadExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);  
            PollingSynchronizer read = new PollingSynchronizer(incomingQueue, dbConncetion);  
        threadExecutor.submit(read);  

    }catch (Exception e){  
    e.printStackTrace();  
    }  

}  

@SuppressWarnings("unused")  
private void shutDownThreads()  
{         
    try {  
        threadExecutor.shutdown();  
        //DB handling should be moved to separate DB class  
        dbConncetion.close();  

    }catch (Exception e){  
    e.printStackTrace();  
    }  

}  

/** Here This Queue passes the messages and have the collection of outgoing message 
 *  
 */  

//private Collection<KpiMessage> outgingQueue = new ArrayList<KpiMessage>();  
//have to implement something here for future  

     public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {  
     RunnableController controller = new RunnableController();  

    System.out.println(incomingQueue.size());  

    controller.initializeDb();  
    controller.initialiseThreads();  

    Thread.sleep(3000);  
    System.out.println("Polling");  

  }  

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend using a BlockingQueue for doing so, instead of a simple ArrayList. Just change the type of your `incomingQueue` variable. Then you can have another thread (or a thread pool) doing something like

```
//pseudocode
while (true) {
   // it polls data from the incomingQueue that shares with the producers
    KpiMessage message = this.incomingQueue.take()

   //Then process the message and produces an output... you can put that output in a different queue as well for other part of the code to pick it up
}
```

A good example on BlockingQueues can be found here http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/blockingqueue_example.shtml

Comment: BTW, yours is a typical producer-consumer problem. Just google up how to solve it in java 5 (queues were not available on previous sdks and using monitors is rather annoying) and you will get tons of examples.

Comment: thank you do you mean to say, I should use queue instead of list in my Poller class...!!

Comment: Yes, and there are many reasons to that:

1 - a common array list is not thread safe, hence you will have race condition issues unless you synchronize it

2- consumers can block and passively wait for new messages to be put on the queue by the producers

Comment: @Claudion Fernandez So should I change the type from List to queue in my Poller class as well....